# Add a day to an input of type datetime-local

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, date, input

Best regards I have a question since what I am trying to do is add one more day to an input that is of the datetime-local type than and I try with JQuery but it only works for me if the input is of the date type which I would like to know how doing it works for me with datetime-local This is the code I take as a reference that works with date:

```js
$('#checkInDate')[0].valueAsDate = new Date();

    $('#checkInDate').change(function() {
    var date = this.valueAsDate;
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    $('#checkOutDate')[0].valueAsDate = date;
    });

    $('#checkInDate').change();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Date Ini:  <input type="date" id="checkInDate">
Date Out: <input type="date" id="checkOutDate"> <br>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `datetime-local` input doesn't have a `valueAsDate` property. But you can use `valueAsNumber` instead.

So whenever you set the value, cast the date object to a number with `input.valueAsNumber = +date`, and whenever you retrieve the value, cast it to a date with `new Date(input.valueAsNumber)`

Also, for setting the initial value of the date, to limit the precision to minutes you can do `Math.floor(Date.now() / 6e4) * 6e4`, and to account for the timezone, you can subtract the timezone offset.

```js
$('#checkInDate')[0].valueAsNumber = 6e4 * (Math.floor(Date.now() / 6e4) - new Date().getTimezoneOffset());

$('#checkInDate').change(function() {
  var date = new Date(this.valueAsNumber);
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
  $('#checkOutDate')[0].valueAsNumber = +date;
  
  console.log(new Date(this.value)) // retrieving as data
});

$('#checkInDate').change();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Date Ini:  <input type="datetime-local" id="checkInDate">
Date Out: <input type="datetime-local" id="checkOutDate"> <br>
```

Of course, when retrieving the data to use in the backend or store in a DB, make sure to construct the date object from `this.value` instead of `this.valueAsNumber`.

Comment: How can I do so that it only shows me the hour and minutes

Comment: see updated answer